# Slide menu header?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Dear Stackoverflow users, I'm very new to coding and this is my first post here! My first app I'm developing right now has a slide menu(hamburger), and while I have found a great tutorial on how to make one, with it came a very annoying white header(which also turns the notch black if the menu is opened when I test build on iPhone X and up) that I want to just be transparent. Later on I plan to place an image over it, so my app looks like the mobile version of this site warp.net.

here's the code for the menu!

```
    //Slide menu below
    
    menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
    menu?.setNavigationBarHidden( true, animated: false )
    
    SideMenuManager.default.rightMenuNavigationController = menu
    SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    }

    @IBAction func didTapMenu(){
        present(menu!, animated: true)
        
    }
}

class MenuListController: UITableViewController {

    var items = ["Latest", "Releases", "Video", "Shop"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "dreamTangerine")
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self  , forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row ]
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "dreamTangerine")
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    }
}
// End of Slide Menu"
```

Any kind of help would be very gladly appreciated!

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of what is currently looks like? and refer the github link of libraries you used

Comment: Sure! Sorry I didn't think of this myself! https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1627/AYZxcH.png
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/3735/p3N2ad.png

Comment: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#preview-samples